# getControl.setDefaultView in crm 2011 causes an error

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I used

```js
document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("defaulttype", "2");
document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("lookuptype", "2");
Xrm.Page.getControl("customerid").setDefaultView("{A9AF0AB8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-C6281FED7FAB}");
```

in `Form_onchange()`, and it gives me this error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method".

If I close the popup window, the program actually works fine.

What might be the problem?

P.S. I'm running IE9 and the error message didn't specify which method is not supported.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? *You* may know where the code fails but you're asking everyone to reads dozens of lines of code to find whatever you are referring to. Finally it's not even clear what your question is... Please help us to help you and be more focussed and clear with your question.

Comment: Can you debug your code line by line in the browser?

Comment: I commented on the line where the program dies.  I don't know why it's hard to find what I'm referring to.  That line fails probably because o.selectedIndex is -1.  But I didni't write the big truck of code above.  I only wrote those three lines at the very top, and what I want to know is why it's behaving the way it is right now and how may I fix it without touch that big truck, but only those three lines.

Comment: "I don't know why it's hard to find what I'm referring to..." It's hard because there's 70-odd lines of code there and it's not clear a) why you quoted the `handleView` function at all b) that you had also gone on to annotate that code. ;-)

Comment: Oh, handleView is where the code behaves unexpectedly, and I thought it'd be helpful for people to understand what's happening.  Guess not...  What DO you need to know then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"{A9AF0AB8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-C6281FED7FAB}" isn't a valid GUID.  Make sure to use the exact GUID of the View.

Ok, I've never seen anyone X out the GUID...

Anyhow, take out line 2 and see if that works.  I checked back on some of my code and I have lines 1 & 3.

Also, your lookup needs to already be able to switch from accounts to contacts (type code 1 -> 2) within the interface (as a user not via javascript).

Comment: I know.  I used the correct GUID of the view.  "{A9AF0AB8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-C6281FED7FAB}" isn't what's actually in my code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried to take out line 2, but the same problem still occurs.  And I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "lookup needs to already be able to switch from accounts to contacts (type code 1 -> 2) within the interface (as a user not via javascript)"..?

Comment: When you click the lookup and open the dialog, there should be a "Look for" drop down.  This drop down should include Contact and shouldn't be disabled.

Comment: The Look for drop down is indeed disabled.  Thank you very much.  How do I enable it?

Comment: Your relationship is only to the account at this point.  The "parent" lookups that have account & contact available in the drop down are built into CRM, so I'm not sure you can add one of those.  If you need both the parent and contact, you can always add a contact lookup field and then just show/hide which lookup field is needed.